# Customizing the media player in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my iphone app i want to change the buttons of media player.for example (play/pause)button,(full screen button)etc.Is this possible.please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry but I'm afraid that you can only create you own.
You will need to hide the controller:

```
[moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
```

and use a [UIToolbar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html).